# How to use the Inception v3 model to calculate the feature vector of PNG images in the transfer learning

Tags: tensorflow, png, python-3.5

I'm using transfer learning in TensorFlow.I need to use Inception V3 model to calculate the feature vector of a picture.My code in the calculation of JPG format pictures no problem, but the calculation of the PNG format will be wrong.

```
# read model
with gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, MODEL_FILE), 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

bottleneck_tensor, jpeg_data_tensor = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, return_elements=[BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_NAME, JPEG_DATA_TENSOR_NAME])

......

# get imagepath
image_path = get_image_path(image_lists, INPUT_DATA, index, category)
# read image
image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

# calculate the feature vector
# **This statement is wrong when png images**
bottleneck_values = sess.run(bottleneck_tensor, {jpeg_data_tensor: image_data})
```

Console error includes：

```
...... 

Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89 0x50

......

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Invalid JPEG data, size 19839
     [[Node: import/DecodeJpeg = DecodeJpeg[acceptable_fraction=1, channels=3, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_import/DecodeJpeg/contents_0)]]
```

I guess the wrong key is to read the picture of the code, but I don't know how to modify it to support the PNG format, can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.
Although I can't modify it to support the PNG format, but I can read the PNG image and convert it to JPEG format.
Add code as follows：

```
import io

......

# get imagepath
image_path = get_image_path(image_lists, INPUT_DATA, index, category)
# read image
data = open(image_path,'rb').read()
ifile = io.BytesIO(data)
im = Image.open(ifile).convert('RGB')
ofile = io.BytesIO()
im.save(ofile, 'JPEG')
image_data = ofile.getvalue()

# calculate the feature vector
bottleneck_values = sess.run(bottleneck_tensor, {jpeg_data_tensor: image_data})
```

This method does not generate new images in the disk,that's OK!

Answer (score 0):

Can you download some other images and see if they work? The problem is really your image loading I think...

Otherwise, try reading an image with pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = plt.imread('image.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you.I've found a solution. Although I can't modify it to support the PNG format, but I can read the PNG image and convert it to JPEG format.